# How to add new lines to existing CSV file using R

Tags: powerbi

I've created a "log" file with PowerBI, adding a new row to an existing CSV file with some values everytime the data source is refreshed.

I've created the following  R script that is executed as a step in the query editor:

```
# 'dataset' contiene los datos de entrada para este script
# ------ DATOS DE ENTRADA -----------------------------------
carpeta <- 'REGISTRO'
nombre_archivo <- 'REGISTRO.csv'
pais <- 'COLOMBIA'
entidad <- dataset$BANCO
moneda <- dataset$MONEDA
fase <- 'TRANSFORMACIÓN'
# -----------------------------------------------------------
onedrive <- gsub("OneDrive - ", "", Sys.getenv("OneDrive"))
ruta <- 'Aplicacion Cobro Alarmas - Documentos'
importe <- sum(dataset$IMPORTE)
Fecha <- trunc(Sys.time(),"mins")
num_lineas <- nrow(dataset)
num_clientes_distintos <- length(unique(dataset$NUMERO_CLIENTE))
num_facturas_distintas <- length(unique(dataset$NUMERO_COMPROBANTE))
archivo <- 'BCSC'
archivo_log <- paste(onedrive, ruta, carpeta, nombre_archivo, sep="\\", collapse="")
x <- data.frame(fase,pais, entidad , Fecha, num_lineas, importe, moneda, num_clientes_distintos, num_facturas_distintas,archivo)
write.table(x, file = archivo_log, sep = ";", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
x <- dataset
```

The CSV file is updated, but every execution insated of inserting only one row, it get a lot of new rows are inserted with the same values, but with different timestamps: Fecha <- trunc(Sys.time(),"mins")

It seems the script is being executed several times (like once per row in the 'dataset'), but I need it to be executed only once per execution.

Any ideas to fix it?

Thanks in advance